# Mounting 65” TV to 3/4” OSB

Tags: mounting, studs, television, mount, osb

I am a new home owner and was looking to mount my 65” TV to a wall. The total weight of the TV with the TV Mount is 50lbs. I used a Stud Finder and determined due to the stud placement, I would be unable to centre the TV correctly. The studs are 24 cm apart but to have the TV centred, I would need to cover 48 cm across to another different stud.

As a result, I was looking to use 3/4” OSB that is approximately 52” wide by 13.5”. I purchased #10x2.5” Wood Screws that I would be drilling through the OSB, drywall, and into the studs. Due to the width of the OSB, I was going to drill into 3 studs with 3 screws each for a total of 9. First off, will this be secure enough or should I use another material than OSB or different screws.

Lastly, I will be mounting the TV Mount to the OSB with the provided four 50mm Lag Bolts. I know these will go through the OSB and then into my drywall too. Would you recommend I get a shorter Lag Bolt? Or will this whole configuration be secure?

Appreciate any and all help!

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/206728/18078

Comment: Id use plywood rather than OSB

Answer (score 7):

Rather than OSB, I'd use two lengths of 2x4 placed horizontally and screwed into the studs.  Then attach your TV mounting bracket to the 2x4s with properly sized screws.

While it will probably work, a 65" TV is on the heavy side and I'd be concerned that the OSB may not be strong enough to hold the screws.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it. Round off the ends for a nicer look and if you have a router, do the edges.

Comment: Add some sanding and stain and all yours friends will want you to make more.

Comment: A lot depends on the weight of the TV and how far it is from the wall.